# PyCharm Incremental Diff as in SublimeText

Tags: pycharm, diff, gutter

Simply put, I'm looking for SublimeText  Incremental Diff on PyCharm

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/incremental_diff.html

[image]

It works even without git or any vcs. But on PyCharm I can't find anything close to it. Chances are I just did not find it, right?

Comment: Maybe https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/comparing-files-and-folders.html or https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/differences-viewer.html

Comment: Naa I'm talking about those color marks in the gutter

Comment: I think this functionality isn't available, I tried searching for it some time back and also couldn't find it :/

Comment: It's unbelievable, PyCharm is so packed with stuff and then they miss this little thing

Comment: Yep, after years of using PyCharm daily I just discovered a couple of new functionalities I really needed this last week. At least the official documentation has gotten a lot better, there used to be plenty of features that were "under-documented". (So this feature might be in there, somewhere...)

Comment: When you say *"miss this little thing"* the fact that Python is constantly changing (with half of the typing module being deprecated) for me explains a lot of the feature instability we've seen in PyCharm. The devs have to implement new language features constantly only to deprecate them a few minor versions latter.